# php oracle 12c: not all variables bound in

Tags: php, sql, oracle, oracle12c

I want to be able to log in either as an admin, or a regular user,  admin account(table: adminisztrator),  regular user(table: felhasznaloAdatlap).

My problem is, this:

> error
>   Warning: oci_execute(): ORA-01008: not all variables bound in D:\xampp\htdocs\Adatb2\adatb2\stage4\login.php on line 35
>   Warning: oci_fetch_array(): ORA-24374: define not done before fetch or execute and fetch in D:\xampp\htdocs\Adatb2\adatb2\stage4\login.php on line 36
>   error

line 35 is oci_execute($stid); and i can't really figure out why it is not working.

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once('connection.php');

if (isset($_POST["uname"]) && isset($_POST["psw"])){    
    $stid = oci_parse($conn, 'SELECT * FROM adminisztrator WHERE adminEmail=:adminem and adminJelszo=:adminpsw');    
    if($_POST["uname"] == ":adminem" && $_POST["psw"] == ":adminpsw" ){    

        $username = $_POST['uname'];
        $password = $_POST['psw'];
        oci_bind_by_name($stid, ':adminem', $username);
        oci_bind_by_name($stid, ':adminpsw', $password);
    } else {
        unset($stid);
        $stid = oci_parse($conn, 'SELECT * FROM felhasznaloAdatlap WHERE felhasznalonev=:names and felhasznalojelszo=:psw');
        if($_POST["uname"] == ":names" && $_POST["psw"] == ":psw" ){

            $username = $_POST["uname"];
            $password = $_POST["psw"];
            oci_bind_by_name($stid, ':names', $username);
            oci_bind_by_name($stid, ':psw', $password);
        } else {
            echo 'error' ;
        }    
    } 
}



oci_execute($stid);
$row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC);

if ($row) {
    $_SESSION['uname']=$_POST['uname']; 
        echo '<script language="javascript">';
        echo 'alert("Felhasznalo sikeresen bejelentkezett")';
        echo '</script>';
        header("Location: index.php"); 
    }else {
        echo 'error';
        exit;
    }

?>
```

Comment: `if($_POST["uname"] == ":names"` then when you bind that you will be binding the value `':uname'` which I doubt will be any use to you. So either the IF test is wrong or the data makes no sense

Comment: But if they are not set you will not bind any values, So basically the flow of the script if not working correctly

Comment: Ditto this `if($_POST["uname"] == ":adminem" && $_POST["psw"] == ":adminpsw" ){` makes no sense and probably should not be there

Comment: thank you, i deleted the ifs, worked around a bit and it works =).